# ejecutable en Mac con pyinstaller no corre

Tags: python

Todos los archivos de mi aplicación están en una misma carpeta (*.py, *.ui, *.ico) empleo pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icono=ardilla.ico main.py me genera la carpeta dist a la cual le adiciono todos los archivos *.ui ejecuto el main.app y no corre nada. Estoy trabajando en VMware con Mac OS Catalina y Python 3.9 Alguien me podría indicar qué estoy haciendo mal? pues lo mismo hice en windows 10 y me genero el ejecutable bien.

Comment: En Mac existe el cmd? En caso de que exista prueba abrir tu exe escribiendo en el input el directorio del exe. Si te muestra un mensaje de error podrías agregarlo a la pregunta porfa???

Comment: Es decir escribe en el cmd de Mac c:/eldirectoriodetuexe/ejecutable.exe